# INT or TIMESTAMP for the change time column in a logging table?

Tags: mysql, logs, timestamp

We're having an argument over what to use for storing change date in a new log table for our site.

One side says, use `INT` for the timestamp, storing the UNIX timestamp. We can convert the datetime query in PHP to a UNIX integer and query based on that (WHERE log_date BETWEEN [convert 12/25/2012 to timestamp] AND [convert 12/31/2012 to timestamp]).

The other side says, use `TIMESTAMP` for this; we can then use the native tools to query. (WHERE log_date BETWEEN "2012-12-25" AND "2012-12-31").

Since this is a logging table, we're not concerned about the 1970-2038 range of TIMESTAMP.

Which makes more sense?

Comment: the 1970-2038 range could bite you if you were using INTs too

Answer (score 3):

I have done it both ways. I prefer using TIMESTAMP because it makes adhoc queries easier. If you only use a GUI to query the logs, then use whatever that programmer wants.

This one boils down to a style question because there isn't much difference in the functionality or performance.

ed

Answer (score 2):

It depend on your use case , queries and MySQL version.
Basically I suggest `timestamp` instead of `int` because of this reasons:

1-You have `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` features in `timestamp`.

2-`timestamp` are more flexible in time zone functionality.(actually you should consider MySQL's TIMESTAMP data type does not store timezone,but DATETIME does, As Bill Karwin said in comments)

3- benchmarks show `timestamp` are more better in performance in most use cases.
for [myisam](http://gpshumano.blogs.dri.pt/2009/07/06/mysql-datetime-vs-timestamp-vs-int-performance-and-benchmarking-with-myisam/) and [innodb](http://gpshumano.blogs.dri.pt/2009/07/06/mysql-datetime-vs-timestamp-vs-int-performance-and-benchmarking-with-innodb/)

4-You can use datetime function for date comparision, addition, substraction, range lookup etc, without the need to use FROM_UNIXTIME() function - it will make it easier to write queries that can use indexes.

Comment: +1, but fwiw MySQL's TIMESTAMP data type does not store timezone.  DATETIME does.

Comment: @BillKarwin I edited my answer. thank you for your attention.